# PHPoAuthLib how to set Access Token?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, oauth-2.0

Hello I'm using this library : https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel
it is based on PHPoAuthLib for Laravel.

There is examples for OAuth logins but I want to set my own access token and make some requests.

I can't find a function like setAccessToken()

What do I need to to after creating a consumer after this?

```
$fb = OAuth::consumer('Facebook');
```

Comment: It is discussed here with examples for Oauth1 & 2:
https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib/issues/167

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps too late but I don't have found anything in the code to do this. So you need to do the same thing as the code does :

```php
<?php
use OAuth\OAuth2\Token\StdOAuth2Token;

$token = new StdOAuth2Token();
$token->setAccessToken( 'CVZYTDVK.BJGYZGKHJBKJHGV....' );

$fb      = \OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook' );
$storage = $fb->getStorage()->storeAccessToken( 'Facebook' , $token );

dd( $fb->request( '/me' ) );
```